# Download all files matching regex using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, regex, http, download

I need to download all files matching a given pattern (regex or wildcard) using nodejs. I need something like

```
      const url = `http://my.domain.com/my-file-${version}-${some-random-number}.zip`;
      const request = http.get(url, function (response) {
         // Handle the response
      }
```

On the server I have a single file that matches the criteria but the problem is that I don't know the `some-random-number` variable.

Is it possible to download the file using regex or wildcard?

Comment: If the server `my.domain.com` is your, you can config it to allow you to do that

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't :(

Comment: In fact how can I check if the domain supports this?